# Xmas-colored tiles

Tags: tiling, polyomino

If you subdivide a 2x2 tile into 4 unit squares and then color each unit square either red or green, then there are $2^4=16$ ways you can do this as shown below:

[image: 2x2 tiles colored red or green in 16 ways]

Can you use all 16 tiles (rotations allowed) to tile an 8x8 square so that whenever a unit square from a tile shares a common edge with a unit square from an adjacent tile, then the two unit squares will have the same color?  Flipping the tiles over is not allowed.

BONUS:  Can you find a symmetrical solution?

---

**To allow new users to solve this puzzle and earn reputation points, I encourage all users whose reputation is 200 or more to not post an answer until 48 hours after this question is posted. Thank you!**

---

This puzzle is a slight variant of David Butler’s puzzle:  [Panda squares](https://blogs.adelaide.edu.au/maths-learning/2016/10/19/panda-squares/).

---

Comment: Flipping might as well be allowed. All flips can be achieved with rotation.

Comment: Then you can try it without rotation.

Comment: @FlorianF I have :o) and not only is it possible without rotation, it is toroidally possible without rotation.

Comment: I too tiled the doughnut...

Comment: The doughnut solution can obviously be repeated to tile the plane, resulting in a really nice tiling pattern. When I was a kid, the seats of my Dad's Citroën CX car had that pattern woven into it. I would get carsick from looking at it, but I still like the pattern.

Comment: The pattern is even unique.  Except for reflections.  Which we can do without flipping anything :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time's up.  Here is a pattern.

> [image]
>
>  It is just one solution.  There are others given the freedom of rotations.
>
>  This solution has the extra constraint that no rotation is allowed and it works on a torus.  In other words it still works if we repeat the pattern horizontally and vertically.
>
>  With these additional constraints this solution is unique except for translations (mod 4) and flipping.

And giving in to the social pressure asking to do more and provide a symmetrical solution, here it is:

> Here are reflective-symmetrical solutions.
>
>  [image] and
>
>  [image]
>
>  These are the only I found.
>  You can go quite far actually by deduction alone.  For instance the unicolor squares must be in the diagonal and cannot touch.  It is quite fun.

Comment: The extra constraints make this a 2x2 [De Bruijn torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_torus)

Comment: Is there a solution that has reflectional or rotational symmetry?

Comment: Since there is only one red square, rotational symmetry is impossible.  Maybe a reflectional symetry along the diagonal is possible.

Comment: Reminds me the [pattern](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/2d/using_tilemaps.html#x2) used to define tilemaps in some game engines.

Comment: I think those two symmetric solutions are the only ones, apart from rotations and colour inversions.

Comment: @FlorianF If you felt pressured by me to give a symmetrical solution, I apologize!

Comment: As I said, it was fun.